# Need help identifying pin connector

Tags: identification, connector, pins

I received a replacement part for a machine I operate, that used to have 1/4" spade terminals, but now apparently comes with round pin connectors that I cannot identify. It seems like they may be better quality than spade connectors so I'd like to find the female counterpart so I can modify the part where these plug in rather than modifying the pins back to spade connectors.

[image: pin connector]

The pin is 2mm ∅ by 10mm long, and the threaded portion is an M5x0.7 thread. There are no visible markings I can find. It would be extra nice to confirm the temperature rating of these connectors as well, as they must operate in a ~200C environment.

Edit: more detailed picture

[image: pin connectors]

The plastic housing is free to spin on the male tip so that the thread engages the female connector and secures the tip in-place by pushing against the wider shoulder. There is not enough slack in the wire to displace the housing around the female connector, however I assume the construction must be similar.

Comment: Look super close at the plastic housing.   Are there ANY markings that might be a manufacturers logo or anything else?

Comment: You could write a letter the OEM as well.. just ask them what it is.   Maybe you'll even get a reply!

Comment: I have called the US division of the company, but they're somewhat bad about getting back with me, and they are just the sales division. The main company is German, and they don't handle end user support in any way. I have inspected very carefully, and am quite sure there are no part numbers or logos on the part. I was kinda hoping it was a generic-ish form factor. I am aware that 2mm bananna plugs exist, but I need a female end connector that will take high temperature, and if I search for anything related to "bananna plug" all I get is audio equipment...

Comment: An option when all else fails, start digging through Mouser or Digikey 'connectors' and maybe you'll find something.  Good luck!

Comment: Also peruse German connector manufacturers directly such as Harting.  Seems German engineers prefer to source German parts (maybe they get a price break.)

Comment: "M5x0.7 thread" -- Are you referring to the ridges in the plastic housing, close to the contact? From the picture, they look parallel to me, not a thread. Can you confirm either way, please?

Comment: I see your bounty. But what works better than a bounty is for you to take the time to answer our questions fully and clearly, please.

Comment: @DavideAndrea please see additional picture. Also note the bounty was added after a long period of no one taking interest in the question, and before your question. All prior comments had been asked and answered. Without adding a bounty the question would have remained buried and you would likely not have found it. The actual part in question is the connector for the heater cartridge in the build surface of an EOS M100 LPBF printer.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. That helps a lot. I am sorry that I can't identify it.

Answer (score 2):

> The pin is 2mm

Those are [tip connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=misc_signal_exposed_pin_conn&s=Tip) (my site). They are compatible with DVM meter probes.

> I'd like to find the female counterpart

https://www.digikey.com/short/mwzfvp2r

> 200C environment.

The only one I see that could survive such temperatures is one without a plastic housing:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/keystone-electronics/6097/316534

Keystone 6097

[image: Keystone 6097]

{Digikey}

Comment: Seems like the connector must be custom, and this may be the closest I'm gonna get.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I never got a bounty before!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon configuration...you can find a similar part [here](https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/file/17699/download?token=yGqUw0xy), but it's rated only to 50C.  200C is a fairly robust requirement; you can spend a while looking through [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/banana-and-tip-connectors/jacks-plugs/302?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWMAJhoE4BWEAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfSURrkQyYiJF5knYgJytJQA), but unfortunately you have to go to the spec since they're not sorted by operating temp range.